# WPF + Toolbar y su grip

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

Necesito ayuda.
Tengo una barra de tareas desde la que necesito acceder a otras opciones. Lo que me gustaría es que el grip no se viera y que las opciones se desplieguen al presionar el primer botón.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con la propiedad `ToolBar.OverflowMode`.

El valor predeterminado es 'AsNeeded`, que indica que el elemento se pone en el menú adicional cuando no tiene espacio.

Se pueden utilizar los valores `Always` o `Never` que siempre ponen el elemento en el menú adicional o impide que el elemento se mueva al menú adicional respectivamente.